# How can I get a AVG using a GridView is ASP.net

Tags: sql

I am able to retrieve data from SQL database using a gridview, and it works fine. But I am trying to get an AVG on a specific column but I am not able to do it.
This code lets me see what I want:

```
try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select fecha, Nota from X where Department like '" + "Department1'" + " and Analyst like '" + analyst + "%'", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

How to get an AVG of Nota for all rows for that specific department?

Comment: Side notes: There's no point catching an exception you will immediately re throw. Simplify your code and omit the try catch. Use parameters in your sql too

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT AVG(Nota) from X WHERE Department LIKE 'Department1' AND Analyst LIKE 'analyst%' GROUP BY Department`

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this:

```
    //try
    //{
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
select 
  fecha, Nota, avg(nota) over(partition by department) as avgnota
from X 
where 
  Analyst like @ana", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ana", analyst+"%"); //later, google for "can we stop using AddWithValue already"
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    /*}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }*/
```

Changes:

- removed unnecessary exception "handling"
- added a window function average calculation of avg nota per department
- removed single department from where clause (not much of an average!? But you can add it back if you want
- removed unnecessary string stop start concatenation
- converted sql to use parameters - see http://bobby-Tables.com

If you have only a single department you can have the datatable calc the average instead, by adding a DataColumn with an Expression property set to  `"AVG([nota])"` but it will only be reliable if your table contains a single for department. To have a datatable with multiple departments and calculate the average per department it will be need to be in a dataset, with a relation to a parent table and the average will function along the relation- more hassle than its worth

Comment: Thanks, just one more question, Department1 has 4 scores, so when I run this the average will show 4 times. Is there a way that this average appears only once?

Comment: avgnota
70.000000
70.000000
70.000000
70.000000

Comment: How do you want that to appear though? You ask a simple question but it has a broad range of answers that are highly dependent on the overall look of the ui  you want to build.

Comment: Hello, just want to have the average of all score in just one field or textbox. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I mean, everything that you told me to do worked perfectly, that is what I needed it. This just came up, to have that average and place it into a TextBox

Comment: It might be simpler to do it outside of the gridview, if the grid is only showing one department. `sometTextbox.Text = dt.AsEnumerable().Average(r => r.Nota)`

Comment: In the grid I have 3 departments, I did the following:                           TextBox1.Text = dt.AsEnumerable().Average(r => r.Nota);                                        'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Nota' and no accesible extension method 'Nota' acceptng a first argument of thype 'DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using dorective or an assembly reference) CS1061

Comment: 3 distinct departments or 3 rows of the same department? This is what I mean when I say you ask a simple question but the respoonse is complex. Please ask a new question that includes a screenshot of how you want the final UI to look. Trying to do this in comments will take a long time because I cannot understand what you want your UI to look like in the end